# hover and click interaction with animated gif

Tags: jquery, hover, animated

I have a logo showing by default.
When hovering, I want to show another image.
When clicking I want to show a third image, which is an animated gif.

I have this all working but I need a delay in place so that the animated gif can run completely, even if the hover is lost. I've tried a bunch of things and no joy. Here's the code:

```
    $(function() {
        $(".logo img").hover(
            function() {
                $(this).attr("src", "http://[URL]/images/logo-hover.png");
            },
            function() {
                $(this).attr("src", "http://[URL]/images/logo.png");
            }                         
        ); 
    });        

    $(function() {
        $(".logo img").click(
            function() {
                $(this).attr("src", "http://[URL]/images/logo-animate.gif");
            }                         
        ); 
    });
```

Comment: Presumably after the delay you want the hover action to work again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make a div or and iframe, put the images over each other and control their zIndex and opacity via jQuery animate

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS for this:

1. .element { content:url("img1") }
2. .element:hover { content:url("img2") }
3. .element.clicked { content:url("img3") }

And in JS just add and remove `clicked` class when needed.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4c0uzhh8/1/

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate solution (note the animation will continue to run after the click)**

Unbind `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events on click.

```
$(function() {
    $(".logo img").click(
        function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "http://[URL]/images/logo-animate.gif");
            $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        }                         
    ); 
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u50fxhzh/1/)